# MPMoviePlayer Controller blackscreen when Status bar hides

Tags: ios, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to get a videostream to work.
My Code works super, it starts playing (fetches the Video From an url provided by Apple Support Sites - the player plays the first four seconds of the Video and then when this little status bar thing wants to automatically hide the player goes blackscreen (with Status bar I mean the indicator of Time, with the fullscreen Button etc.).
I cant Post sourcecode right now because I am writing with my iPhone, so I will do that later...
Hope That my description helps you to understand and maybe you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my .h File:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp;
```

In my .m File:

```
        NSURL *mediaURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov"];
        mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        [mp setShouldAutoplay:YES];
        [mp setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming];
        [mp setContentURL:mediaURL];
        [mp setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded];
        [mp setFullscreen:NO];
        [mp setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeNone];
        [mp prepareToPlay];
        mp.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 220);
        [self.view addSubview:mp.view];
```

this is working fine :)